# How can I change real time update rate and/or max step size of ros-gazebo physic from command line once ros-gazebo has started?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
I am launching Gazebo through ROS.  I want to change the max step size and/or real-time update rate after launching Gazebo, preferably from the command line. I know that usually they are set as fixed in the .world file but how do I change that during run-time from the command line?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24126/how-can-i-change-real-time-update-rate-and/or-max-step-size-of-ros-gazebo-physic-from-command-line-once-ros-gazebo-has-started?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2019-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Rahul !

I never have tried using the command line to set the physics simulation properties of the world, always I had used the definition inside the ".world" to set the properties.

I know that using Gazebo with ROS (gazebo_ros package) you can find a service to set some properties (time_step, max_update_rate, gravity, etc). Then you can use "rosservice call /gazebo/set_physics_properties ..." and to check if finally, you can modify the simulation parameters that you wish.

I hope my answer can help you, let me know if you have a good result.

---

Originally posted by [Saimon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4224/saimon/) with karma: 26 on 2019-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2019-12-03**:
Thanks, Saimon. Your proposed method worked fine for me.